# Python scripting assistance

Tags: python, regex

I'm very new to python scripting but I'm wanting to copy/paste strings similar to the one below into a script that prints out the results in a particular format. I want each value below to print and I'm pretty sure regex would be needed, ie: to parse the IP value I'd use the following regex *^(?:[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$*. I'm just not sure how to incorporate it into the script.

**Example of string to copy/paste:**

Virus: Stuxnet

Computer: HP_1234

Domain: ABC\

IP: 192.168.10.1

User: user1

File: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\malo.png

Date/Time: 10/19/2015 22:23:57

Result: Cleaned

Virus Scan Engine: 421.6000.1009

Virus Pattern: 419.9890.0009

**Snippet of what I've pieced together so far in terms of coding:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

alert = raw_input("Copy/paste alert and press Enter:\n\n\n ").split()

print "==============================================================\n\n"

print"Please take a look at the following issue. \n\n"

print "Infection Name:"
print "IP Address:"
print "Infected file location:"
print "Date/Time: "
print "Domain: "
```

How would I go about parsing the copy/pasted string and getting the appropriate fields filled out from this parsing? I thought re.findall may be the solution but that doesn't appear to work. I think adding .split to the end of raw_input will allow me to use %s for variables and I think that puts me on the right track, but again, I'm unsure. Sorry if this description is unclear..again I'm brand new to scripting.

Comment: Can you provide an example of output which you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you simply need to input the data and format how it is presented, it seems like a simple parser might work:

First cut and paste the string into a text file (which I call cut_and_paste.txt):

```
Virus: Stuxnet
Computer: HP_1234
Domain: ABC\
IP: 192.168.10.1
User: user1
File: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\malo.png
Date/Time: 10/19/2015 22:23:57
Result: Cleaned
Virus Scan Engine: 421.6000.1009
Virus Pattern: 419.9890.0009
```

Now you can load the file and parse the string into a Python dict with a pretty simple script:

```
with open('cut_and_paste.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data = dict()
    for line in infile:
        pair = line.strip().split(':')
        data[pair[0]] = pair[1]
```

note that this could be done more "Pythonically", but I used a form that is easier to follow since you said arent so familar with scripting.

The basic idea is to open the file in read mode (the 'r') and call it 'infile', then create a Python dictionary which allows you to organize the data into key: value pairs. For each line in the file "strip" the line, remove any whitespace (basically the newline character in this case) then split the line on the colon. Finally, dictionaries are populated by setting dict[key] = value, so in the next line everything to the left of the colon becomes a key, everything to the right becomes a value.

When you generate the report, you can then recover the data using keys:

```
print 'Take a look at the following issue:'

print 'Infection Name:', data['Virus']
print 'IP Address:', data['IP']
...
...
```

If you just want to produce a simple report like this, then file parsing should do the trick. Regex would come into play if you want to do something more complicated with the values themselves. For example, you might want to look for IP addresses within a certain range, etc.

But, from what I can gather from the question, it seems that a pretty simple parser like this should do the trick.

Hope it helps

**EDIT based on your follow-up question:**

There is a more robust way to recover value from a dictionary (that I probably should have used in the original answer, but I was trying to keep it simple)

The conventional way to get data from a dictionary is as stated in the original answer:

```
print data['key']
```

this is short and simple, but as you have found throws a KeyError if a key doesnt exist. You can overcome this with a small modification to use the dictionary's get method:

```
print data.get(key)
```

or

```
print data.get(key, default)
```

In both cases I have a string *key* which represents whatever key you are looking for.

If I modify part of the report generate code with (for example) a typo that result in a key that doesnt exist you can see how these work:

```
print 'Infection Name:', data.get('Virusx')

print 'Infection Name:', data.get('Virusx', 'Not Found')
```

Whereas the original code will throw a KeyError, these
these each produce the following output:

```
Infection Name: None

Infection Name: Not Found
```

In the first case, when 'Virusx' cant be found in the dictionary the default behavior is to return None, which is then converted into a string 'None'

This method also allows you to add a second argument that defines how you want Python to respond when a key can't be found. In this case, I am telling Python to return a string 'Not Found', although you can replace this with any string to suit your needs. For example, returning an empty string can be an effective way to indicate missing data.

**2nd edit**

Based on the new information, it looks like you need to use the *maxsplit* option of the *split* method. This allows you to specify the maximum number of "splits", and it works like this:

```
input_string = 'File: C:\Windows'

insufficient = input_string.split(':')
print insufficient

correct = input_string.split(':', 1)
print correct
```

I put the results next to each other to make the difference more apparent:

```
insufficient --> ['File', ' C', '\\Windows']
correct -->      ['File', ' C:\\Windows']
```

Basically it sounds as though the string was split too many times, and you were likely accessing only the first two segments (thus, losing the remainder).

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Now i'm working on how to handle errors that arise when one of the pieces of data is missing, which happens at times. The error i'm 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tm_1.0.py", line 24, in <module>
    print "IP Address:", data['IP']
    KeyError: 'IP'

To handle this i thought adjusting the code to look like the following would help but that doesn't appear to work: 

    with open('c_p.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data = dict()
    for line in infile:
  try:
   pair = line.strip().split(':')
   data[pair[0]] = pair[1]
  
  except KeyError: 
   print('')

Comment: I just editted the answer with some additional info and a slight modification that will help solve this issue.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Last thing, there is an area in the string i'm copy/pasting that reads **'File: C:\Windows'** but when I print, everything after the 2nd colon gets stripped out. 

<br>so this: </br>
<br>print "Infected File Location:", data.get('File', '')</br>

<br>gives me **C**</br>
<br>instead of C:\Windows\whatever</br>

Comment: OK, I think I see the problem. Check out the latest update for an explanation. Cheers.